# bash if logical boolean string

Tags: bash, if-statement, boolean

I am *not* looking for a different way to accomplish the apparent intention.  I'm looking to *understand* why this *exact* syntax is not working.

```
[root@lvs ~]# while true;do
> echo "Would you like the script to check the second box ([y]n)?"
> read ans
>         if [ "$ans" == "n" ];then
>                 echo
>                 echo "bye"
>                 exit
>         elif [ "$ans" != "" -o "$ans" != "y" ];then
>                 echo "Invalid entry..."
>         else
>                 break
>         fi
> done
Would you like the script to check the second box ([y]n)? **"Should have continued"**

Invalid entry...
Would you like the script to check the second box ([y]n)? **"Should have continued"**
y
Invalid entry...
Would you like the script to check the second box ([y]n)? **"Correct behavior"**
alskjfasldasdjf
Invalid entry...
Would you like the script to check the second box ([y]n)? **"Correct behavior"**
n

bye
```

Here's a reference that's identical to so many others i found. I *understand* what it's doing, it's using the non logical's for AND and OR when everything I've read said that it should be using logical bools.

http://www.groupsrv.com/linux/about140851.html

Ok so here it is, with Nahuel's suggestion behaving how I had originally expected it to:

```
[root@lvs ~]# while true;do
> echo "Would you like the script to check the second box ([y]n)?"
> read ans
>         if [ "$ans" = "n" ];then
>                 echo
>                 echo "bye!"
>                 exit
>         elif [ "$ans" != "" -a "$ans" != "y" ];then
>                 echo "Invalid entry..."
>         else
>                 break
>         fi
> done
Would you like the script to check the second box ([y]n)?
asdfad
Invalid entry...
Would you like the script to check the second box ([y]n)?

[root@lvs ~]# while true;do
> echo "Would you like the script to check the second box ([y]n)?"
> read ans
>         if [ "$ans" = "n" ];then
>                 echo
>                 echo "bye!"
>                 exit
>         elif [ "$ans" != "" -a "$ans" != "y" ];then
>                 echo "Invalid entry..."
>         else
>                 break
>         fi
> done
Would you like the script to check the second box ([y]n)?
y
[root@lvs ~]# while true;do
> echo "Would you like the script to check the second box ([y]n)?"
> read ans
>         if [ "$ans" = "n" ];then
>                 echo
>                 echo "bye!"
>                 exit
>         elif [ "$ans" != "" -a "$ans" != "y" ];then
>                 echo "Invalid entry..."
>         else
>                 break
>         fi
> done
Would you like the script to check the second box ([y]n)?
n

logout
```

Comment: BTW, `==` is a bug that is sadly accepted by bash. Only `=` is the POSIX way to test for equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that : [ "$ans" != "" -o "$ans" != "y" ] is always true because of the or and the negation. $ans cannot be equal to "" and to "y".

Try replace these lines

```
if [ "$ans" == "n" ];then 
elif [ "$ans" != "" -o "$ans" != "y" ];then
```

by these

```
if [ "$ans" = "n" ];then 
elif [ "$ans" != "" -a "$ans" != "y" ];then
```

or these

```
if [[ $ans == n ]];then 
elif [[ $ans != "" && $ans != y ]];then
```

The easier is to do is a case:

```
case $ans in
  y) echo "yes"
  ;;
  n) echo "no"
  ;;
  *)
  ;;
 esac
```

also `break` must be used only in a `for` or `while` loop, or in a `select` but it is missing in your post .

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses everyone.  The -o example that I used in my post was just one of what seemed like 95858943737495048 woefully futile attempts.

I just tried Nahuel's suggestion above and by god IT WORKED!!  Now I just need to unerstand.

My logic was as follows:

Comment: My logic was as follows:
Ask question ([y],n) and devise the most efficent method for correctly handling any type of possible user input.
So, if the user presses "n" - exit the scritp
If the user presses something like "vi45 08noisdfgoh qer g08haergrh8" display error and prompt for retry.
3. 1 and 2 leave y and "" as the only remaining keystrokes

Comment: What I still don't understand is why there dosnt seem to be anyway for an "OR" to truly work with strings in bash...Why is that?

Comment: For example, the tcpdump below has a conditional filter to capture udp broadcast's sourced from port boopc [OR || -o] tcp unicasts destined for tcp port 57000...and it works just find:

[root@lvs1 ~]# tcpdump udp src port bootps or tcp dst port 57000
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes
08:05:13.145024 IP dc1.x.net.bootps > 255.255.255.255.bootpc: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length: 300
08:05:32.099530 IP precision.x.net.14044 > lvs1.x.net.57000: S 444213637:444213637(0) win 8192 <mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK>

Comment: there is no problem with or and strings for example `[ "$ans" != "" -a "$ans" != "y" ]` is equivalent to `[ \! \( "$ans" = ""  -o  "$ans" = "y" \) ]` the problem is the `-o` with `!=`

Comment: But in your fix, your not using an OR your using and AND...that's totally different and the source of my anguish.

I don't like using break but it works, i tried false in place of break but it doesn't work.  Now if i set t=true, then did a while $t = true and swapped break for t=false, that works but I'm on an efficiency quest and I can't figure out how to set false, so ill stick with the break for now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand, why do you use -o in the elif. I would use "||" or "OR" operator. When you use two conditions in if, you should use double [[ and ]].
So if you use:

```
    elif [[ "$ans" != "" ||  "$ans" != "y" ]];then
```

it works fine.

Comment: [ "$ans" != "" -o "$ans" != "y" ] is always true

Answer (score 0):

also logically its a flawed way of doing things.
firstly using case would be best in this scenario, secondly you are looking for == n then stating if it is blank or not equal to yes - so although no is caught out in first if statement in theory it would still meet second criteria

surely the most logical way to ensure input is 100% would be

```
 if [ "$ans" == "n" ];then
                 echo
                 echo "bye"
                 exit
         elif [ "$ans" == "y" ];then
                 echo Yes
                        break;

        else

                 echo "Invalid entry... >$ans<"
         fi
```

Comment: Please don't proliferate the `==` bug. The only way to properly `test` for equality is `=`.

Comment: My logic was as follows: Ask question ([y],n) and devise the most efficent method for correctly handling any type of possible user input. So:
        1. If the user presses "n" - exit the scritp
        2. If the user presses something like "vi45 08noisdfgoh qer g08haergrh8" display error and prompt for retry.
        3. 1 and 2 leave y and "" as the only remaining keystrokes
How is this flawed?

Comment: its flawed because you are looking for a yes no and yet you seem to be processing the anything else before yes as above example it processes yes/no then anything else- the above example i given you is not any different to using a case statement of n) something y) something *) error